# multiple level logging to multiple appenders

Tags: logback

I have a logback.xml which is configured to write multiple levels of log of various classes to logfile A.

```
<appender name="logA" >
--
--
</appender>
<logger name="A" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="A.B" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="A.C" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="A.D" level="WARN"/>
<logger name="A.E" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="A.F" level="DEBUG"/>

<root level="INFO">
   <appender-ref ref="logA" />
</root>
```

Now i want another log file LogB with all the debug log without changing anything to logA

I tried below but its writing all the debug log to logA as well.

```
</appender name="logB">
--
--
</appender>
<logger name="A" level=DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="logB" />
</logger>
```